Keep OpenGL application working when RDP is no longer active
I have a GUI application doing 3D rendering using OpenGL. The application has a automation mode where the actual GUI automation is controlled and automated by another AutomationHost program.  The application needs to run on a Windows Server VM and in that automated mode the application needs OpenGL to function properly.
After updating Qt and Coin3D, the application, and a newer OpenGL 3.x to function install Mesa3D to enable software rendering and while that let the application works on the server, the application now stops working when the RDP session is inactive, disconnected or minimized.
I found this command to convert the terminal session to a console session
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (tscon.exe %%s /dest:console)

That works as a solution but is not ideal. Every time you have to RDP to the server, you need to run that command before disconnecting. The application will also not function properly after a reboot. It requires logging in with a remote desktop manually and running the command to get the application running after a reboot.
I need way to keep the GUI context or session active without any Remote Connection that:

Works on reboot without manual intervention.

Works on an RDP session. An alternative would be  VNC or some other remote desktop protocol, but would that require manually launching the application so it runs in whatever session VNC uses and keeps active?

Allow you to still see and interact with the GUI if you do manually login to Remote Desktop for debug purposes.

Does not require installing unsigned drivers.


